# After Angular 6 update, ng build --prod yields "Error: Expected to find an ngsw-config.json configuration file"

Tags: angular, service-worker

The update went fine, but now when I build, I get the following error.

> Error: Expected to find an ngsw-config.json configuration file in the
>   /Users/nathanielmay/Code/firebaseTest folder. Either provide one or
>   disable Service Worker in your angular.json configuration file.

I looked in my `angular.json` and found that on this line:

```
"ngswConfigPath": "/src/ngsw-config.json",
```

> Property ngswConfigPath is not allowed.

I can't find an api for the new angular.json, but it seems as if I need to specify the path in a different way.

`ng update @angular/pwa` didn't work either.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure how `"ngswConfigPath": "/src/ngsw-config.json"`, was added, but I removed it and it built fine.

Next issue I faced was that `ngsw-config.json` has been moved out of `src` and to the project root during the upgrade. I had to copy my updates into the root `ngsw-config.json` for the service worker to register properly.

Answer (score 38):

Please make sure to build your app in root folder. I had the same issue and building from the root folder solved my issue.

Comment: my project was angular multi project, and instead of being in root folder for build command I was in "project" folder, and after going to root it worked with no problem

Answer (score 6):

For my case issue was connected with `/` sign added at the front of the path, so instead of `"ngswConfigPath": "/src/ngsw-config.json"` I've used `"ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json"` and issue fixed.

Comment: I had the same issue and removing the trailing / fixed it.

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrading from ng5 to ng6. Removing the trailing `/` fixed it for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the file ngsw-config.json is generated but is on a different location.
First disable Service Worker in your angular.json/angular-cli.json configuration file. Then run `ng build --prod` on your terminal. It should run without errors.

Then enable the service worker in your angular.json/angular-cli.json and run the `ng build --prod` command again in your terminal.

Comment: This worked for me using @nrwl/nx.  Remove `serviceWorker: true` from `angular.json`, use `ng build myapp --prod`, revert angular.json, and build again.  Presto.

Comment: @sneurlax I use @nrwl/nx too, but your solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) of the official angular website for PWA (service worker).

Anyway, you can run this command to automatically configure **PWA** for your application.

```
ng add  @angular/pwa --project *your-project-name*
```

Or, if you looking for a specific version of PWA, then you can run this (the word "version" in the command below refers to the version of PWA. for example: @13.2.0):

```
ng add  @angular/pwa@verion --project *your-project-name*
```

By running this command the following changes will be done:

1. The *manifest.webmanifest* will be created on **src** folder
2. Also, the *ngsw-config.json* will be created on **root** directory of the
3. And, some minor changes (service worker configurations) will be done on *angular.json* file