# Angular service worker not found/registered error when building app

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I am getting the following error when trying to build my app using ng build --prod

```
Error: Expected to find an ngsw-config.json configuration file in the 'project' folder.
```

If I run ng serve --prod the app runs successfully but I get a console `error TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.`

I have tried moving the ngsw-config.json file to the app root and within the src directory but nothing works.

My angular.json file is as follows. I am using angular 6. Please assist.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ngJava": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ngJava",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ngJava:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ngJava:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ngJava:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ngJava-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ngJava:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ngJava:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ngJava"
}
```

Comment: have you registered your service worker in your app.module.ts?

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal yes I have imported it and registered it `ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })`

Comment: try `environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js') : []` and put your _ngsw-worker.js_ in your _src_ folder

Comment: You can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71828633/6666348

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (see below ) when I placed the ngsw-config.json in src. The correct folder for it is the root of your app. In your case it should be the ngJava folder. You don't give much more information about the project (e.g a snapshot of your folder structure) and I am not sure on how you implemented the sw in the first place.

If the file is in the correct spot, I  would recommend making sure you implemented the sw correctly by running `ng add @angular/pwa --project ngJava`

Additional instructions are at https://v6.angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

If that still not works please feel free to contact me and i'll be glad to help you troubleshoot.

```
Error: Expected to find an ngsw-config.json configuration file in the /home/alberto/Workspaces/KiAndCo/kiandco/ClientApp folder. Either provide one or disable Service Worker in your angular.json configuration file.
```