# Angular PWA missing ngsw.json and ngsw-worker file

Tags: progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

I have a problem with `@angular/pwa`. when I am building in production mode I am not getting `ngsw-worker.js` and `ngsw.json` files in my dist folder.

the pwa version am using is:

`@angular/pwa: ^0.13.8`
`@angular/service-worker: ~7.1.0` 
`@angular version 7`

Thanks in advance

Comment: In angular.json have (configuation setting) do you have "serviceWorker": true

Comment: Yes I do @PeterS

Comment: what build command are you using exactly? Can you display the output of the dist directory as a screen shot?

Comment: You can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71828633/6666348

Answer (score -1):

This answer is only relevant when:

- you use [nrwl/nx](https://nx.dev/)

  - which [decorates the ng command](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/getting-started/nx-and-cli#decorating-angular-cli)
- and [angular configuration composition](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#apply-specific-build-options-for-just-one-locale):
  i.e. `ng build client --configuration=production,variant`

## nx version 11

Now the workaround for version 10 (see below) does not work anymore!

- [closed-nx#4296: Cannot pass in multiple configurations using -c since nx 11](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4296)
- actual fix should be handled in: [nx#2839: NX does not handle multiple configurations: nx run app:build --configuration=production,stage-env](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2839)

a workaround can be to opt-out of the nx [ng-cli-decorate patch](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/getting-started/nx-and-cli#decorating-angular-cli)

quote from [nx#4452](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4452#issuecomment-755854101):

> To opt out of this patch:
>
> Replace occurrences of nx with ng in your package.json Remove the
> script from your postinstall script in your package.json Delete and
> reinstall your node_modules

## nx version 10

**To fix the issue** (we use nx version 10) we replaced:

- <s>`ng build client --configuration=production,variant`</s> with
- `nx build client -c=production,variant`

The problem was, that nx did not pass the configuration correctly to `ng` and thus `ng` did not build the production configuration (thus no PWA/service-worker)

Links to nx issues:

- [#2839: NX does not handle multiple configurations: nx run app:build --configuration=production,stage-env](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2839)
- [#4296: Cannot pass in multiple configurations using -c since nx 11](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4296)

Answer (score -2):

You can copy the files from the node_modules folder (from a prompt in your project folder):

```
cp node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js ./src/ngsw-worker.js
cp node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-config.json ./ngsw-config.json
```

You may also need to make sure your service worker is registered. Nice presentation on the subject at: https://javascript-conference.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Automatic_Progressive_Web_Apps_using_Angular_Service_Worker_Maxim_Salnikov.pdf